# User-defined function return type int thrown error

Tags: sql-server, function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfCheckMaxPlayer] 
    (@LId varchar(50),
     @SId varchar(50),
     @TId varchar(50))
RETURN int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TotalCount AS int;
    SET @TotalCount = 0

    SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(*) 
    FROM
        (SELECT
             *,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [LId], SId, PId ORDER BY EntryId DESC) rn 
         FROM
             [dbo].[LTeams] 
         WHERE
             [LId] = @LId AND [SId] = @SId AND TId = @TId) a 
    WHERE
        a.rn = 1

    RETURN @TotalCount
END
```

This function throws an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udfCheckMaxPlayer, Line 8 [Batch Start Line 470]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Return'.
>
> Msg 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure udfCheckMaxPlayer, Line 17 [Batch Start Line 470]
>   A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context

Comment: Should be "returns int" not "return int"

Comment: that query seems to be doing a lot of unncessary work BTW. There is no need to calculate row numbers to get a distinct count. Should be able to use `SELECT @TotalCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Pid)
         FROM
             [dbo].[LTeams] 
         WHERE
             [LId] = @LId AND [SId] = @SId AND TId = @TId` as `[LId], SId` both have equality conditions on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **RETURNS** instead of **return** while declaring return variable.